# Functions satisfying $f^2+g^2=1$

Tags: geometry, functions, derivatives

I am asked to prove that if $f,g$ are differentiable functions and $f^2(x)+g^2(x)=1$ $\forall x$, then there exists a differentiable function $\theta$ so that $f(x)=\cos(\theta(x))$ and $g(x)=\sin(\theta(x))$, $\forall x$.

The proof can't use complex numbers. I'm suggested to use $\theta' = fg'-gf'$, but I haven't been able to make any considerable progress.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need $f$ and $g$ to be continuously differentiable?

Comment: The exercise just says differentiable, but lets assume that $f,g \in C^\infty$

Comment: That's evident to define the function $\theta(x)$ such that $\theta(x)=\arccos(f(x))$ because $|f(x)| \le 1$. Then you can deduce that $g(x) = \sin(\theta(x))$  About the differentiability of $\theta$, it's straightforward also because $f$ and $\arccos$ are differentiable functions.$$$$
Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: @MarkSaving The result is correct as stated, but the proposed proof, integrating $\theta'$, needs that this integral exists, so continuity of $\theta'$ is desirable. (Even without any differentiability, continuous $f$ and $g$ will give a continuous $\theta$, and then $\theta$ will be as nice (differentiable, $C^1$, $C^\infty$) as $f$ and $g$ are.)

Comment: @NN2 Your solution doesn't work. Consider $f = \cos$ and $g = \sin$. Then your solution gives $\theta(x) = \arccos(\cos(x))$ which is not differentiable.

Comment: @MarkSaving In your example, $\theta = \arccos(cos(x)) = x$.  the function $\theta: x \to x$ is differentiable, right?

Comment: @NN2 $\arccos(\cos(x))$ does not always equal $x$. Consider $x = 2\pi$. Remember that $\\arccos(y) \in [0, \pi]$ for all $y$. So it won't be differentiable at multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @NN2 The equation $\arccos(\cos x)=x$ holds only for $x$ in the range of your chosen branch of $\arccos$ (usually $[0,\pi]$). To handle more general $x$, you'll need to switch from one branch of $\arccos$ to another appropriately. Saying precisely how to do that is the (topological) essence of the problem.

Comment: @MarkSaving , AndreasBlass : Yes, thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 4):

Pick $\theta_0$ such that $f(0) = \cos(\theta_0)$ and $g(0) = \sin(\theta_0)$.

If you don't assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable, things get a little bit hairy and require a high-level result. I will provide this proof now. Define $S = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ to be the unit circle. Then since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we have a continuous map $h : \mathbb{R} \to S$ defined by $h(x) = (f(x), g(x))$.

Now consider the map $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to S$ defined by $\pi(x) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$. It is a well-known fact that this is a [covering space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space).

Because $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to S$ is a covering, $\pi(\theta_0) = h(0)$, and $h$ is continuous, there exists a unique continuous map $\theta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h = \pi \circ \theta$ and $\theta_0 = \theta(0)$. This follows easily from the path lifting property of covering spaces. This is therefore a $\theta$ such that $\cos \circ \theta = f$ and $\sin \circ \theta = g$.

It now remains to show that $\theta$ is a differentiable function. Consider some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\pi$ is a [local diffeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_diffeomorphism), we can take some neighbourhood $U$ of $\theta(x)$ such that $\pi|_U : U \to \pi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $\tau : \pi(U) \to U$ be the inverse diffeomorphism of $\pi|_U$. Let $V = \theta^{-1}(U)$; then $V$ is an open set, and $x \in V$.

We see that $h|_V = \pi|_U \circ \theta|_V$. Then $\tau \circ h|_V = \tau \circ \pi|_U \circ \theta|_V = \theta|_V$. Since $\tau$ and $h|_V$ are both differentiable, so is $\theta|_V$. That is, $\theta$ is differentiable in an an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $\theta$ is differentiable at $x$.

Then $\theta$ is differentiable.